# Custom Open Graph FAcebook Share Link on Newsletter HTML code

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, newsletter

I'm recently managing a Newsletter Database with about 500k suscribers. I would like to add a FB custom share link, that displays different information on user FB wall, according to each Newsletter subject. The head of each Newsletter already has the og meta tags, but the traditional sharer.php link does not seem to read them. I know this may be pretty obvious but I'm totally new with Open Graph. Any Idea how I should proceed and build the share custom link, right now, it doesnt display anything I wrote on those meta og tags. I would like to add that I still don't have access to the main domain of the company I'm making the newsletter of, but as far as I have seen, they have  not included in the website the og meta tags. Could this be the problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Of course the meta tags have to be on the URL that you are sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much, just was granted the access to the website hosting and added those meta tags and now is working as expected. 
Is there any method, to select a specific share post img, instead of the fixed on those meta tags. I mean, each Newsletter share link will have different subject/events, images and summaries, where I should store this information and data in order to be share accordingly?

Comment: No, you can not change those properties dynamically. If you want different _content_ to be shared, then you need to share different _URLs_.